# Git cvsimport a specific tag

Tags: git, cvs, git-cvs

Upon using below command:

```
git cvsimport -C MYGITBRANCH -r cvs -k -v -d ${DESTDIR} MYCVSMODULE
```

I was successfully able to import my master branch with all history.
Where DESTDIR is the cvs repo url.

Now I am trying to use this command to import a specific branch which was tagged from above module. I searched on git cvsimport documentation at https://git-scm.com/docs/gitcvs-migration but failed to help myself.

Pls guide me If you have ever experienced/achieved this.

Answer (score 0):

Cvsimport should import all branches. Check your new git repo. You should have a branch for every CVS branch.